Issue with unfilled Google ads on url path change
I am building a Single Page Application using NUXT 3 framework where user can generate new colors palettes by clicking on space bar (similarly to Coolors). Every time user hit the space bar, a new set of color will be displayed and the URL path will be update.
(eg. url: my-domain.com/generate/palette1 --> user generate a new palette: my-domain.com/generate/palette2)
When user first open the generate page, the ads are successfully displayed. But then as soon as they decide the generate a new palette (ie. updating the url path), the google ads disappear and I get the data-ad-status = unfilled.
Has anyone else ever had this problem ? How would you fix this issue so that ads remain visible on the page when the URL path is updated without breaking Adsense policy about automatic ad refresh:
Publishers aren't permitted to refresh a page or an element of a page without the user requesting a refresh
So far I have successfully create my Ads component which contains the Google Ads logic:
Ads.vue component:
<script setup>
 const props = defineProps({
    adSlot: Number,
 })

 onMounted(() =>{
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 })
 onUpdated(() =>{
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 })
</script>

<template>
          <ins class="adsbygoogle rounded-md"
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXX" :data-ad-slot="adSlot.value">
          </ins>
</template>

Then this component is included in my dynamic generate page:
[Generate].vue page:
<Ads :adSlot="XXXXXX" style="display:inline-block;width:384px;height:80px"/>

With this setup, my ads are correctly showing up on first page load but as soon as user update the path, the ads disappear.
